# Scrollbar into a python tkinter discussion

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

ia_answers= "test\n"
input_frame = LabelFrame(window, text="User :", borderwidth=4)
input_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

input_user = StringVar()
input_field = Entry(input_frame, text=input_user)
input_field.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
'''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
canvas = Canvas(window, borderwidth=0, background="white")
ia_frame = LabelFrame(canvas, text="Discussion",borderwidth = 15, height = 100, width = 100)
ia_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP)
scroll = Scrollbar(window, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
canvas.create_window((4,4), window=ia_frame, anchor="nw")
ia_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas:onFrameConfigure(canvas))




user_says = StringVar()
user_text = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=user_says, anchor = NE, justify =   RIGHT, bg="white") 
user_text.pack(fill=X) 

ia_says = StringVar()
ia_text = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=ia_says, anchor = NW, justify = LEFT, bg="white") 
ia_text.pack(fill=X) 

user_texts = []
ia_texts = []
user_says_list = []
ia_says_list = []
def Enter_pressed(event):
    """Took the current string in the Entry field."""
    input_get = input_field.get()
    input_user.set("")
    user_says1 = StringVar()
    user_says1.set(input_get + "\n")
    user_text1 = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=user_says1, anchor = NE, justify =   RIGHT, bg="white") 
    user_text1.pack(fill=X)
    user_texts.append(user_text1)
    user_says_list.append(user_says1)
    ia_says1 = StringVar()
    ia_says1.set(ia_answers)
    ia_text1 = Label(ia_frame, textvariable=ia_says1, anchor = NW, justify = LEFT, bg="white") 
    ia_text1.pack(fill=X)
    ia_texts.append(ia_text1)
    ia_says_list.append(ia_says1)

input_field.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
window.mainloop()
```

Hi, I try to build a GUI with tkinter but I've got two problems, the LabelFrame/Canvas doesn't fill entirely the window and I can't get the scrollbar to automatically scroll down.
Can you help me with that, thank you very much.
Ilan Rossler.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using labels in a frame in a canvas instead of something simpler like a Text widget?

Comment: Normally I use Labels in a LabelFrame but i've read that you need to put a Canvas inside a Frame, but that wasn't clear. I don't use a Text widget because I don't want that the user can edit the text into the "Discussion" LabelFrame

Comment: Are you aware you can disable editing of the text widget? You can use it in read-only mode so that the user can't edit the text. you can also do right- and left-justified text.

Comment: I didn't knew that :( have you a link to a explaination ?

Comment: I've found one, thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually control the width of the inner frame since it is being managed by the canvas. You can change the width in a binding to the `<Configure>` event of the canvas (ie: when the canvas changes size, you must change the size of the frame).

You'll need to be able to reference the window object on the canvas, which means you need to save the id, or give it a tag.

Here's an example of giving it a tag:

```
canvas.create_window((4,4), window=ia_frame, anchor="nw", tags=("innerFrame",))
```

And here's how to change the width when the canvas changes size:

```
def onCanvasConfigure(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    canvas.itemconfigure("innerFrame", width=canvas.winfo_width() - 8)

canvas.bind("<Configure>", onCanvasConfigure)
```

To scroll down, call the `yview` command just like the scrollbar does. You need to make this happen *after* the window has had a chance to refresh.

For example, add this as the very last line in `Enter_pressed`:

```
def Enter_pressed(event):
    ...
    canvas.after_idle(canvas.yview_moveto, 1.0)
```